# Как максимально обезопасить хранимые SSH-ключи

Tags: безопасность, ssh

Храню несколько SSH-ключей, хочу максимально обезопасить их. Лежат в `~/.ssh`.

Можно ли (и нужно ли) что-то сделать, чтобы повысить безопасность их хранения, например от случаев несанкционированного доступа к компу.

- Обфусцировать имена, чтобы неясно было какой к чему подходит?
- Переложить в другое место?
- ?

Использую OS X и Ubuntu.

Comment: Лучше исключить несанкционированный доступ к компу

Comment: @Mike: само собой ) Но бывает всякое.

Comment: Вообще можно все. Но imho игра не стоит свеч. Меожно куда то их поглубже в файловой системе копировать. Но копировать каждый раз перед использованием и потом удалять. И что бы следов в истории не оставалось. А если делать скрипты для этого их могут увидеть и узнать пути. Мне пока один способ в голову пришел - написать модуль ядра, файловую систему что бы она даже когда примонтирована давала доступ к фалам только N минут после запуска какой нибудь утилиты которая пароль спросит :)))

Comment: Или подружить ssh с токеном, хранящем ключи и включаемым в USB ... Не знаю готова ли она к этому, но может быть и тогда это правильный выбор параноика, главное токен не забывать в компе

Comment: @Mike: да уж, жесткий способ. Я тут придумал такое решение — договориться с админами, чтобы мне завели моего пользователя на нужных серверах, а потом зарегать там собственный ключ с passphrase.

Comment: А чем это лучше стандартной парольной защиты без всяких ключей

Comment: Как вариант, взять имена и ключ захешировать по определенному ключу, ключ желательно помнить тогда многие факторы кроме как потеря памяти исключаются_) ну либо тогда хранить на флешке, как предлагал Mike. Плюс написать скрипт который расшифрует вам эти ssh-ключи при запуске определенной программы, в которой вы либо указываете ключ, либо файл с ключем для расшифровки

Comment: @Mike: ключ и пароль это больше, чем только ключ или только пароль.

Comment: Хранить приватные ключи, защищенные passphrase на зашифрованном USB накопителе в сейфе. Вот только от терморектального криптоанализа вас все равно ничего не спасет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

с публичной частью ключа (хранящейся в том же каталоге `~/.ssh`) ничего делать, конечно, не надо. разве что удалить (если очень хочется) — она легко восстанавливается из секретной части:

```
$ ssh-keygen -y -f секретная-часть > публичная-часть
```

---

секретную же часть можно (и, пожалуй, нужно) зашифровывать паролем:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p -f секретная-часть
```

а для того, чтобы не вводить пароль каждый раз при необходимости воспользоваться ключом, задействовать *ssh-agent*.

в современных версиях популярных дистрибутивов операционной системы *gnu/linux* программа *ssh-agent* обычно уже установлена и даже (по умолчанию) запущена в качестве «прокладки» между *x-сервером* и пользовательской *x-сессией*. благодаря чему в переменных окружения всех *x-клиентов* (в том числе и *x-эмуляторов* терминала) присутствуют переменные `SSH_AGENT_PID` и `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, что позволяет всем заинтересованным программам связываться с процессом *ssh-agent-а*.

задача этого агента — держать в памяти расшифрованный секретный ключ(-и) и, при обращении к нему, зашифровывать/расшифровывать этим ключом переданную информацию. в явном виде расшифрованный ключ(-и) агент **не** «отдаёт».

---

посмотреть список хранимых (в памяти) агеном в данный момент ключей можно командой:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

удалить все ключи из памяти можно командой:

```
$ ssh-add -D
```

конкретный ключ:

```
$ ssh-add -d /путь/к/секретной-части
```

добавить ключ (потребуется ввод пароля для расшифровки, если файл зашифрован, как предложено выше) можно так:

```
$ ssh-add /путь/к/секретной-части
```

если путь не указан, по умолчанию будут добавлены ключи, хранящиеся в файлах `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` и `~/.ssh/identity`.

но ещё, пожалуй, лучше — добавлять ключ лишь на указанный промежуток времени:

```
$ ssh-add -t время /путь/к/секретной-части
```

время можно указать в виде, описанном в секции *time formats* в `man sshd_config`. например, `600` или `600s` — на 600 секунд, `1h30m` — на полтора часа.

по истечении указанного промежутка времени данный ключ будет автоматически «забыт» *ssh-agent-ом*.

---

«привязку» к *ssh-agent-у* можно передать «внутрь» *ssh-соединения* с помощью опции `-A` программы *ssh*, или конфигурационной опции `forwardagent yes` в соответствующей «хостовой» секции файла `~/.ssh/config` (или глобально, если употребить **до** первой «хостовой» секции).

благодаря такой «передаче внутрь соединения» можно (с помощью одного и того же экземпляра *ssh-agent-а*) организовывать цепочку беспарольной аутентификации. разумеется, при условии, что на всех машинах в цепочке будет «прописана» подходящая публичная часть ключа.

---

подробнее смотрите в:

```
$ man ssh
$ man ssh-keygen
$ man ssh-agent
$ man ssh-add
$ man ssh_config
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!