# Конвертация пары ssh-rsa (pub) и private ключей в p12 (PKCS12)

Tags: linux, openssl, rsa

У меня есть два ключа.

Публичный pub.key:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB....ykqY
```

И приватный priv.key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEInvOq5PlaQ==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Как их сконвертировать в контейнер p12?

Или как без CA сгенерировать p12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще формат контейнера pkcs12 подразумевает хранение не только секретного ключа, но и «[цепочки доверия от сертификата пользователя до корневого сертификата удостоверяющего центра](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS12)».

но если вам достаточно упаковать только секретный ключ, то надо добавить опцию `-nocerts`:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -nocerts -inkey priv.key -out cont.p12
```

---

похожий вопрос: [Openssl convert .PEM containing only RSA Private Key to .PKCS12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10994116/4827341)

---

p.s. а упаковывать файл с публичным ключом при наличии файла с секретным ключом не имеет смысла: все составные части публичного ключа есть и внутри файла с секретным ключом, и [он легко восстанавливается при необходимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576).