# GUI ssh agent in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Есть два компьютера, на обоих установлена ubuntu 18.04.

На одном из них при попытке подключения к серверу по ssh выскакивает окно, запрашивающее пароль от ключа, в другом - нет (запрашивается сразу пароль от сервера) и мне надо сначала в консоли добавлять ключи в агента чтобы ими пользоваться.

Сверил настройки ssh, переменные окружения и grep ssh-agent -R /etc - всё сходится.

Где это поведение настраивается?

Comment: хрустальный шар подсказывает: `$ chown -R $USER ~/.ssh; chmod -R go= ~/.ssh`

Comment: Права на файлы правильные и сами ключи подцепляются - что ssh, что ssh-agent. Вопрос в том, что на проблемной машине мне нужно вызывать ssh-agent вручную, а на эталонной он вызывается сам - при первом использовании ssh-соединения в любом виде (ssh, git и т.п.).

Comment: ssh-agent действительно запускается, но ещё при запуске x-сессии, чтобы все процессы внутри сессии были его потомками. вкратце см., например, [четвёртый и пятый абзацы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576)

Comment: да, на эталонной машине процесс действительно запущен и переменные действительно есть. Вот я и пытаюсь найти - какой настройкой он запускается, чтобы сделать её на втором компьютере

Comment: да никакой настройки. он напрямую [запускается x-сессией: `$ dpkg -L x11-common | grep ssh-agent`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/x11-common/filelist)

Comment: Нашел что в своих скриптах эти переменные устанавливал и этим видимо мешал X-овому автозапуску. Агент теперь запускается, но пароль при этом всё равно агентом не спрашивается. Если добавить в .ssh/config AddKeysToAgent=yes - то после успешного логина по ssh на сервер ключ в агента добавляется, однако пароль спрашивается ssh-эм, а не через GUI и если я пробую воспользоваться ключем не напрямую через ssh, а например обновить репозиторий из IDEA - то процесс зависает в ожидании подключения. На эталонной машине в том же случае GUI запрашивает пароль и продолжает работу.