# Операции на удалённом сервере по SSH и SCP

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scp

Есть кустарный скрипт:

```
declare NAMECRT="dev"
declare TYPECRT="client"
declare -r SERVER="root@12.34.56.78"
declare -r LOCALUSER="lu"
declare -r REMOTEUSER="ru"
#declare -r NAMESERVER="server_name" # Используется только при TYPECRT="server"

su "${LOCALUSER}" -c "
    cd /home/"${LOCALUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3
    [ ! -d /home/"${LOCALUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki ] && ./easyrsa init-pki
    ./easyrsa gen-req "${NAMECRT}"
"

scp /home/"${LOCALUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/reqs/"${NAMECRT}.req" "${SERVER}":/home/"${REMOTEUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/reqs


ssh "${SERVER}" "
    cd /home/"${REMOTEUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/reqs
    [ -f ./"${NAMECRT}.req" ] && chown -c "${REMOTEUSER}":"${REMOTEUSER}" ./"${NAMECRT}.req"

    su -l ca -c '
    cd /home/"${REMOTEUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3
    if [[ "${TYPECRT}" = "client" ]]; then

        ./easyrsa sign-req "${TYPECRT}" "${NAMECRT}"

    elif [[ "${TYPECRT}" = "server" ]]; then

        ./easyrsa sign-req "${TYPECRT}" "${NAMESERVER}"

    else
        echo "ERROR TYPECRT: ${TYPECRT}"
        exit 1
    fi
    '
"


if [[ "${TYPECRT}" = "client" ]]; then

    mkdir -p /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"/"${NAMECRT}"
    # develop.crt, ca.crt
    scp "${SERVER}":"/home/"${REMOTEUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/issued/"${NAMECRT}.crt" \
    /home/${REMOTEUSER}/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/ca.crt" /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"/"${NAMECRT}"
    # develop.key
    cp /home/${LOCALUSER}/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/private/"${NAMECRT}.key" /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"/"${NAMECRT}"
    # ta.key
    if [ ! -f /etc/openvpn/server/ta.key ]; then
    cd /etc/openvpn/server/
    openvpn --genkey --secret ta.key
    fi
    cp /etc/openvpn/server/ta.key /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"/"${NAMECRT}"

elif [[ "${TYPECRT}" = "server" ]]; then

    # vpn_server.crt, crl.pem, ca.crt
    scp "${SERVER}":"\
    /home/"${REMOTEUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/issued/"${NAMESERVER}".crt \
    /home/"${REMOTEUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/crl.pem \
    /home/"${REMOTEUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/ca.crt" /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"
    # server.key
    cp /home/"${LOCALUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/private/"${NAMECRT}".key /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"
    # dh.pem

    su "${LOCALUSER}" -c "
    cd /home/${LOCALUSER}/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3
    ./easyrsa gen-dh
    "
    cp /home/"${LOCALUSER}"/easy-rsa-master/easyrsa3/pki/dh.pem /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"

else
    echo "ERROR"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -d /etc/openvpn/"${TYPECRT}"/"${NAMECRT}" ]; then
    cd /etc/openvpn/client
    cp -r ./"${NAMECRT}" /home/${LOCALUSER}/down
fi
```

Есть сервер А с VPN, есть сервер B с CA. Скрипт располагается на сервере A и выполняется на нём. Суть скрипта - генерация сертификата. На сервере А генерируется запрос, отправляется на сервер В, подписывается и возвращается.
Всё работает, всё прекрасно.

Но есть неудобство - пароль нужно вводить много раз. Закинуть ключ для ssh, плохой вариант, т.к. если запоролить его, то один фиг придётся каждый раз пароль вводить, а без пароля доступ от одного сервера до другого не хотелось бы делать, иначе теряется смысл в разнесении CA и VPN.

Вопрос, можно ли сделать так чтоб при первом подключении не терялась сессия и в дальнейшем можно было переключаться с удалённого на локальный сервер, выполнять команды и по окончании всего действа завершить сессию?

Comment: шифрованный ключ + ssh-agent не устроит?

Comment: @Fat-Zer поправьте, если не прав. При доступе по ключу, с ключевой фразой её нужно будет вводить при каждом подключении, если без ключевой фразы, то любой вася пупкин сможет сгенерировать себе сертификат или зайти на данный удалённый сервер.

Comment: вообще да, только Васе сначала придётся получить доступ к самому ключу... а вот `ssh-agent` — это утилита, которая как раз позволяет запросить пароль к ключу один раз, а затем безопасно (в рамках возможного) хранить его в памяти в расшифрованном виде и использовать при подключении.

Comment: @Fat-Zer Не очень понимаю принцип работы `ssh-agent`. На `сервере А` генерирую ключ: `ssh-keygen` и соответственно запускаю агент и импортирую в него приватный ключ, затем файл с расширением `.pub` отправляю на `сервер В`. И что получается? С сервера где приватный ключ я могу зайти на сервер с публичным `А -> В` (по-моему фигня какая-то)? Или с сервера с публичным ключём на сервер с приватным `В -> А` (тут тоже фигня, ибо какой смысл от агента, если приватный ключ достаточно в конфиге sshd прописать)?

Comment: Всё примерно как ты описал: на *локальной* машине генерируется пара приватный/публичный ключ, после чего на *удалённый* сервер отправляется публичный и добавляется к списку ключей, после этого возможен доступ с *локальной* машины на *удалённую* по ключу без указания пароля... Но обычно приватную часть ключа дополнительно шифруют, чтобы если злоумышленник завладеет ключом, он не смог бы получить по нему доступ, это шифрование и обеспечивается паролем задаваемым в `ssh-keygen`...

Comment: Так вот, `ssh-agent` и позволяет один раз расшифровать приватный ключ и хранить его в памяти, пока `ssh-agent` не остановят, чтобы пароль от ключа не надо было вводить каждый раз в других утилитах (`scp`, `ssh` итд)... к самому механизму авторизации он имеет опосредованное отношение...

Comment: @Fat-Zer спасибо, всё работает как желалось. Если хотите можете оформить минимально допустимый ответ, зачту.

Comment: @imsysmem, *Не очень понимаю принцип работы ssh-agent* — [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/469363/178576)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если свести задачу к «настроить доступ по ключу к ssh серверу, держать ключ зашифрованным, но не вводить пароль каждый раз», то типовым решением будет — использование [`ssh-agent`](https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=ssh-agent&category=1)'а.

Типовая схема использования:

```
eval $(ssh-agent);
ssh-add # ввод пароля ключа

# вся работа с ssh/scp/sftp итп, повторный ввод пароля не требуется

ssh-agent -k # не забыть остановить агента, когда он более не нужен
```

Кроме того в случае запуска агента из скрипта с последующей его остановкой может быть полезно установить ловушку:

```
trap "ssh-agent -k" 0
```

**upd**
Замечу, что при запуске `ssh-add` без аргументов инициализируются файлы из `$HOME` директории данного пользователя:

`~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` и `~/.ssh/identity`

[`man ssh-add`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add)