# Добавил ключ в ssh-agent, но git продолжает требовать пароль ключа

Tags: windows, git, openssh, ssh-agent

Всем привет! Прошу помощи с настройками ssh-agent: нужно избавиться от постоянного ввода пароля, когда git использует мой ключ.

Ssh-agent, хоть и с перебоями, но был запущен и даже удалось добавить свой id_rsa. Но когда прописал `git pull`, тот снова потребовал пароль. Также NPM из-за этого не может подтянуть пакет, который хранится у нас в приватном репозитории. Помогите, плс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в операционной системе gnu/linux программы ssh/ssh-add связываются с ssh-agent благодаря информации, переданной [через переменные окружения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576). если в ms/windows происходит так же, то, вероятно, отсутствует нужная переменная окружения, или у неё некорректное значение (в gnu/linux оно задаётся самим процессом ssh-agent).

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы гит заработал в связке с plink нужно две вещи

Во-первых, при установке git на пятом шаге выбрать `Use plink` а не дефолтную настройку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вы не помните как ставили -- лучше переустановите git, заново пройдите по всем 12ти экранам установщика.

Второй шаг -- нужно создать переменную окружения GIT_SSH в которой указать для вашего файла plink.exe

Я это делаю при помощи reg-файла:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"GIT_SSH"="C:\\foo\\bar\\plink.exe"
```

Возможно второй шаг не понадобится если у вас окружение putty развёрнуто с инсталлятора или вы ставили галку "установить переменную .ssh" в инсталляторе

---

Update Новый исталлятор git уже не предлагает такого скрина как я приводил выше, просто ставить с дефолтными настройками. Ради любопытства сравнил: в старом инсталляторе после установки файл etc\install-options.txt содержал две строки:

```
Plink Path: C:\mypath\plink.exe
SSH Option: Plink
```

а в новых уже достаточно типовой настройки

```
SSH Option: OpenSSH
```

и всё работает при условии установки `GIT_SSH`.