# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git-commit, git-push

Внёс поправки в проект, закоммитил, думал запушить

```
!git push --set-upstream origin <имя_ветки>
```

Но столкнулся с данной ошибкой. SSH прокинут, вызываю ssh-агента и он работает

```
Agent pid 1054
```

но когда пытаюсь добавить ключ

```
!ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Похожие вопросы не помогли мне решить проблему. Подскажите, где я налажал?

Comment: вызываю ssh-агента — это как? И вообще, какая ОС?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/469423/178576